# WCF Security: what is the way to go with many servers and server identity being unimportant?

Tags: wcf, authentication, wcf-security, x509

So I've done some research and found out that, indeed, WCF [prevents us](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/how-to-use-clear-usernamepassword-with.html) from sending username/password in clear text. The basic argument is that "*it is not secure, because it allows a hacker to intercept credentials*". Hence, a secure channel is required, and for that, the server needs an X.509 certificate.

Ok, point taken. But here's a problem: said certificate needs to be trusted on the client. **But why?**
A trusted certificate is commonly used on Internet-open servers to enable clients to verify the server's identity (i.e. make sure they're not connecting to a bogus server). But what if server's identity is not important in a given context?

My product consists of two applications. Let's call them *client* and *server*<sup>1</sup>.
The basic scenario is this:

1. The user connects to a network that has one or more of those *servers* installed and opens the *client* application
2. The *client* uses WCF discovery to find any servers on the network
   (or, optionally, the user can specify server's address manually)
3. The user chooses which *server* he wants to connect to, and then enters username/password for that server
4. The connection is established, the client does some calls to the server on behalf of the user

One can see how in this scenario, the user doesn't need to verify that the server is not bogus. Even if he wanted to, there is nothing to verify *against*. After all, the only thing we know about the server is that it supports our protocol, and that fact doesn't need verification.

In other words, I need **communication confidentiality** and **client authentication**, but not **server authentication**.

It would be bad enough to ask my customers to purchase a certificate from a trusted authority for every server, but it would be even worse not being able to explain why exactly they need it.

Given all the above mentioned points, I see three possibilities:

1. The WCF designers simply didn't think about this scenario. That is, WCF doesn't support it.
   (at least natively; yes, I am aware of [Yaron Naveh's creation](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html)).
2. I am missing some detail that implies that the certificate does have to be trusted after all.
3. There is a way (unknown to me) to use certificate just for encryption and not for server's authentication, and thus avoid making it a trusted one.

## So the question is:

Which of these three options is the case? And if it's the third one, what is that way? (My fingers are crossed for number 3 :-)

.
.

---

<sup>1</sup> It is important to note that the term "*server*" is not used in the "Internet" sense here. That is, the *server* is not a computer on the web, but rather a **program** that gets installed on some computer, not necessarily even connected to the Internet. And there going to be many of these, installed by different customers on their sites, most times without my direct knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid certificate validation, add following in `system.serviceModel/behaviors/endpointBehaviors/behavior/clientCredentials/serviceCertificate` element:

```
<authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Each "server" doesn't *have to* have it's own *unique* identity. All "server" instances could use the same identity and you just configure the client to expect that identity no matter which "server" it's talking to. That way the client doesn't care as long as all "servers" use the same identity. Essentially this boils down to buying/generating a single certificate for the "server" identity and just making sure that all your "server" instances use this identity in their communication.

From a "server" configuration perspective you just make sure that keypair is installed and use the `<serviceCertificate>` configuration element to use it:

```
<behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
    <!-- ... -->
    <serviceCertificate findValue="AcmeCorpServer" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" X509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
    <!-- ... -->
</behavior>
```

And then on clients you just make sure you have the *public* key installed and configure the endpoint behavior:

```
<behavior name="MyEndpointBehavior">
    <!-- ... -->
    <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="MyClient" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" X509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <serviceCertificate>
            <defaultCertificate findValue="AcmeCorpServer" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople" X509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        </serviceCertificate>
    </clientCredentials>
    <!-- ... -->
</behavior>
```

This is more of a coarse grained approach to security, but it seems like it would fit your particular needs. It's basically like saying "allow my client to talk to any service that might ever exist as long as we can validate the identity to be our identity".

Finally, if you can't/don't want to do this with configuration for some reason (i.e. you can't/don't want to put things into certificate stores) there's ways to do it programatically as well by loading the X.509 certificate manually and then assigning it to the client/server behavior at runtime.

Comment: And what happens to the clients when that certificate expires?

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin: To avoid certificate validation, following can be added at same level as `defaultCertificate` element `<authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />`. That way service authentication will be avoided.

Comment: If the certificate expires both the server and client would need a new copy installed. That's the nature of certificate management. Nothing that can't be maintained easily via Group Policy. I understand you're trying to find a way to bypass having to deal with server auth, but I'm sure your clients would be more upset to know that your software has a security hole in it because you would just blindly send sensitive data to any "server" that poses as an instance. In addition, certificates do not need to be purchased if your clients run their own CA or they can even trust your company's CA.

Comment: @Rest Wing - that's true, but then you give up a major chunk of the security of using certificates in the first place because you're not actually validating that the certs are in fact good.

Comment: @Drew Marsh: I don't see any holes that do not also exist in the case of using the certificates "correctly". Am I missing something? Could you describe the security hole please?

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin: It would allow any certificate to be used on the server side whether the client actually trusts it or not. If you want to skirt validating that you're actually talking to a service that you trust, it will certainly work, but... heck of a security hole.

Comment: @Drew Marsh: And the potential hacker cannot get a certificate from a trusted issuer (i.e. just plain buy it), because?..

Comment: @Rest Wing: Sorry for late reply, been kinda busy. Your advice works perfectly, thank you very much. If you post it in the form of an answer, I will accept it.